# Android Back handler is not working in ignite bowser version 5.1.1 in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
navigation => stack-navigator
├── auth => stack-screen
   ├── login => stack-screen
   ├── register => stack-screen
   ├── forgot-password => stack-screen
├── drawer => stack-screen
   ├── drawer-navigator
       ├── tab-navigator
          ├── home
             ├── home-screen => stack-screen
             ├── home-details => stack-screen
          ├── event
             ├── more-screen => stack-screen
             ├── more-details => stack-screen
```

So, after login it will redirect user to home page but when ever I press back button on home page application must exit but instead of its redirect to login page.

I have set up the exit routes name in root-navigation.tsx file.

```
const exitRoutes = ["login", "home-screen"]
```

I have added some logs in onBackPress function but that function doesn't give call back when we press hardware button in any screen, any one have any idea about it?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: I have created demo project from scratch using ignite-bowser, and onBackPress only calling the welcome screen no other screen